# Cannot change InnoDB full text minimum word length

Tags: mysql, database, performance, full-text-search, innodb

I have a `MySQL 5.7.31` InnoDB table with full text index enabled...

if I search for a longer word, I get results:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE match(my_title) against('landscape in' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

if I search full text for short word (e.g `in`), I get no results

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE match(my_title) against('in' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

the data is there, I can find it with `like %%` query:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE my_title LIKE '%in%'
```

I set these two in /etc/my.cnf, I understand one is for InnoDB and one for MyIsam, I restarted MySQL, I still cannot run the above short full text query.

```
ft_min_word_len=1
innodb_ft_min_token_size=1
```

**Edit:**
If I have a value like `landscape in Paris`, then I get data for `against('+landscape +Paris' IN BOOLEAN MODE)` but NOT for `against('+landscape +in +Paris' IN BOOLEAN MODE)`

Is `in` a reserved word maybe ?

Answer (score 0):

"in" is probably in the "stop list".  Change the specification of the stoplist file.

After changing the min-len or the stoplist, you must rebuild the Fulltext index(es).  (Restarting MySQL is not needed.)

An alternative I used on one situation:  I added `+` to long words.  For example, `against('+landscape in +Paris' IN BOOLEAN MODE)` would probably achieve your goal without changing either the min-len or the stopword list.

(Yes, there are several 'differences' between MyISAM and InnoDB.  I have not found a definitive list in the docs.  Here's my attempt at such a list:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/myisam2innodb#fulltext )